# kusto query to retrieve billing data by day and resource failing

Tags: azure, kql, azure-log-analytics

I have the following K query to retrieve usage and billing information from Azure.

```
//day and the billabledatabytes

find where TimeGenerated between (startofday(ago(32d))..startofday(now())) 
| project _BilledSize, _IsBillable, Day = startofday(TimeGenerated)
| where _IsBillable == true 
| summarize BillableDataBytes = sum(_BilledSize) by Day
```

The query below gets the resourceid and summarises by the date

```
find where TimeGenerated between(startofday(ago(32d))..startofday(now())) project _ResourceId, _BilledSize, _IsBillable
| where _IsBillable == true 
| summarize BillableDataBytes = sum(_BilledSize) by _ResourceId 
| sort by BillableDataBytes nulls last
```

Resourcegroup by the billdatabytes

```
//resourcegroup by billdatabytes

find where TimeGenerated between(startofday(ago(1d))..startofday(now())) project _ResourceId, _BilledSize, _IsBillable
| where _IsBillable == true 
| summarize BillableDataBytes = sum(_BilledSize) by _ResourceId
| extend resourceGroup = tostring(split(_ResourceId, "/")[4] )
| summarize BillableDataBytes = sum(BillableDataBytes) by resourceGroup 
| sort by BillableDataBytes nulls last
```

What am I trying to do ?

I need to get the date, resourceid or resourcegroup, billdatabytes and I have put together the query below, I cannot get it to work.

```
find where TimeGenerated between(startofday(ago(32d))..startofday(now())) project _ResourceId, _BilledSize, _IsBillable, Day = startofday(TimeGenerated)
| where _IsBillable == true 
| summarize BillableDataBytes = sum(_BilledSize) by _ResourceId
| extend resourceGroup = tostring(split(_ResourceId, "/")[4] )
| summarize BillableDataBytes = sum(BillableDataBytes) by resourceGroup , Day
| sort by BillableDataBytes nulls last
```

I get the error

```
Query could not be parsed at '=' on line [1,126]

Token: =
Line: 1
Position: 126
```

Comment: Please try this ->

find where TimeGenerated between(startofday(ago(32d))..startofday(now())) 
| project _ResourceId, _BilledSize, _IsBillable, Day = startofday(TimeGenerated)
| where _IsBillable == true 
| extend resourceGroup = tostring(split(_ResourceId, '/')[4])
| summarize BillableDataBytes = sum(_BilledSize) by resourceGroup, Day
| sort by BillableDataBytes nulls last

Comment: Where are you running the above query? I mean is it resource graph explorer or log analytics? @learner

Answer (score 0):

After a workaround on your issue, I found below reasons for the cause of failure.

Firstly, column names should be unique while storing the data in kql. In your query, you have given the same name `BillableDataBytes` with `summarize` operator. Change the name of the other column to something else. (Eg: `LatestBillableDataBytes`)

Or you can remove the first `summarize` operator and add it at the end to avoid conflicts.

```bash
AzureActivity
| project _ResourceId, _BilledSize, _IsBillable, Day = startofday(TimeGenerated)
| where _IsBillable == true 
| summarize BillableDataBytes = sum(_BilledSize) by _ResourceId, Day
| extend resourceGroup = tostring(split(_ResourceId, "/")[4])
| summarize LatestBillableDataBytes = sum(BillableDataBytes) by resourceGroup, Day
| sort by TotalBillableDataBytes nulls last
```

[image]